# typescript compile error - mui x autocomplete - Property 'code' is missing in type '{.... }' but required in type '{...}'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, material-ui, autocomplete

I'm using mui/material v5.11.13  with nextjs v13.1.1 react 18.2.0 typescript 4.9.4.

nextjs - build/export fails with :
**Type error: Property 'code' is missing in type '{ label: string; }' but required in type '{ label: string; code: string; }'.**

the error is in the following line :

```
value       = {{label : myStateVariable }}
```

my code works as expected when developing , and I can ts-ignore the issue.
but its not how i'd like to run this show. :-)

here's a simplification of the code :

```
<Autocomplete disablePortal disableClearable autoSelect = {true} autoHighlight = {true}
id          = "someId"
options     = {myFunction(parameters)}
renderInput = {(params) => <TextField {...params}   />}
value       = {{label : myStateVariable}}
onChange    = {(event: any, newValue: { label: string, code:string } | null) => { setMyStateVariable(newValue!.label); setSecondStateVariable(newValue!.code);}}
isOptionEqualToValue = {(option,value) => {return( option.label === value.label);}}
disabled    = {....}
>
```

the issue came up when i changed myFunction and added another property called "code".
it now returns an array of objects({ label: string; code: string; })
as stated before, the code works as expected,
on initial render the value of myStateVariable is shown in the autocomplete field.
the options list renders only the label.
on change executes both setState methods ( to store both the label and the code in their respective state variables )
but typescript compilation fails.

**can anyone suggest a solution to this problem?**

Comment: So you're saying that the items don't have a code initially but they receive one after the initial render? Please try to be clear and precise in the English description of your problem.

Comment: myFunction(parameters) builds an array of objects to be used as the data to be displayed. each object has both a label and a code.
( previously, when myFunction returned an array of objects with only a label , the code worked ( onChange only executed setMyStateVariable(newValue!.label) )